# iPhone 4.0 - File Monitor/Listener Notifications?

Tags: ios4

Is it possible to have an application monitor File system changes? Is there something like a file system listener API?

Answer (score 0):

Apps are sandboxed to look only within the app's directories, and only write to the docs directory.  You do not have access to the file system beyond that.

Comment: I think it may be possible to read some system files using GCD  dispatch sources. Any idea on that?

Comment: I do see some docs on how to do this for a particular file, maybe it could be extended to all files, but it is beyond my experience, or what I can see in the docs/examples. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW23